# Bug: Azure DevOps Artifact Feed set wrong Package Dependencies

Tags: azure-devops

We use our private Artifacts Feed on Azure DevOps Server 2020.1 (on-prem). I get a feed `MyFeed` and a feed `MyFeedTest.` I use the `MyFeedTest` for Staging our NuGet Packages. When they are stable, they get pushed to *MyFeed*. If a `NuGet` package in the feed has a dependency on another `NuGet` package in the feed, I use the following line:

```
<PackageReference Include="ext.lib.MyPackage" Version="*" />
```

The issue here is that the Azure DevOps Server determines the dependency by itself, and it takes the Versions from the staging package in `MyFeedTest` for the packages in `MyFeed` even when the package `MyFeedTest` get unlist, even when the whole feed `MyFeedTest` get deleted.

The Azure DevOps Artifact should not determine the dependencies to another package by itself, and it should not ignore the defined dependency setting inside the package project file (`Version="*"`).

In the end, my collogues get the following error in Visual Studio:

[image]

The Dependencies of the Package `ext.lib.MyPackage` on Azure DevOps Server looks like:

[image]

But to remember, the package `ext.lib.DevExpress` in Version `13.1.5.3` do **not** exist after deleting the whole feed `MyTestFeed.`

So how can I solve that? Is it possible to configure the Azure DevOps Server to not behave like this? We can't use staging with that mechanism.

Comment: The Dependencies of the package is determined by the package reference. Azure Artifacts does not automatically add or remove dependencies. If you don't need ext.lib.DevExpress as dependencies any more, you need to remove this package reference in your ext.lib.MyPackage and publish again.

Comment: @WalterQian-MSFT thanks for your reply. We never defined a dependency to the version `13.1.5.3`. We defined `Include="ext.lib.DevExpress" Version="*"` which is what we want. The **Azure Artifacts** set the dependency to `ext.lib.DevExpress (≥ 13.1.5.3)` for the `ext.lib.MyPackage` package by it self, what we don't want. Even after deleting the feed, where `ext.lib.DevExpress 14.1.5.3` was located, the **Azure Artifacts** keep the wrong dependency to `ext.lib.DevExpress (≥ 13.1.5.3)`, what we realy don't want. Artifacts convert `*` to explicit versions, which is not correct and should be fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The issue here is that the Azure DevOps Server determines the
> dependency by itself

This is not determined by Azure DevOps Server, but resolved by NuGet. Version="*" means the highest stable version. Here is the document about [Floating version resolutions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#floating-version-resolutions).
I used [dotnet CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package-dotnet-cli) to create NuGet package. Here is my sample:

1.Add package reference in the "*.csproj" file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="ext.lib.MyPackage" Version="*" />
</ItemGroup>
```

2.Use `dotnet pack` command to build a NuGet package. This will generate a "*.nupkg" file. Change the suffix of this file to zip and extract files.

3.We can find a "*.nuspec" file. Open this file with Notepad, we can find the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/packaging/2013/05/nuspec.xsd">
  <metadata>
    <id>ext.lib.DevExpress</id>
    <version>3.2.1</version>
    <authors>ext.lib.DevExpress</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <description>Package Description</description>
    <dependencies>
      <group targetFramework="net5.0">
        <dependency id="ext.lib.MyPackage" version="1.2.3" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
  </metadata>
</package>
```

So we can find that before this package is pushed to Azure DevOps, the dependencies of the package have been resolved to explicit versions and this is the expected behavior.

If you don't need ext.lib.DevExpress as dependencies any more, you need to remove this package reference in your ext.lib.MyPackage and push your package again.